# realloc(): invalid next size

Tags: c, libcurl, realloc

I'm having a problem with the realloc function. I'm using C only (so no vector) with LibCurl. The problem I'm having is that I'm getting the following error (realloc(): invalid next size) on the 12th iteration of the write_data function (the function I pass to Curl as a callback, it is called each time libcurl has some data to pass back (data is passed in chunks) ).

### Trace:

-Removed-

### Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>

char * Data; //stores the data
size_t  RunningSize;

int write_data( char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream )
{
    size_t ThisSize = (size * nmemb); //Stores the size of the data to be stored
    size_t DataLen = strlen( Data ); //length of the data so far

    RunningSize = (RunningSize + ThisSize ); //update running size (used as new size)

   Data = realloc( Data, RunningSize ); //get new mem location (on the 12th iteration, this fails)
   strcat( Data, ptr); //add data in ptr to Data

    return ThisSize; //the function must return the size of the data it received so cURL knows things went ok.
}

int main( )
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  const char * UserAgent = "";

  Data = malloc(1); //so realloc will work
  RunningSize += 1;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl)
  {
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0 );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.co.uk/" );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, UserAgent );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );

    //preform request.
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    //output the data (debugging purposes)
    puts( Data );

    //cleanup
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    free(Data);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Without seeing your source code it's difficult to know what your table means and what's actually happening. Please put relevant source code in your question.

Comment: What you posted into `pastebin` is virtually useless. There are no calls to `write_data` in your code, so there's no way to figure out what you are doing there.

Comment: @AndreyT: It's a callback, called from inside libcurl.

Comment: As a side note: there's no need to do `malloc(1)` to initialize a pointer for `realloc`. `realloc` can "reallocate" a null pointer without any problems.

Comment: `realloc` is slightly fiddly to use correctly. You need to check that it succeeds by checking for a non-NULL return value, however if it does return NULL then the memory pointed to by the parameter is still allocated needs to be freed. For this reason it is a bad idea to use `x = realloc(x, n)` if `x` is you only copy of the pointer to the memory area. You need to do (something like) `new_x = realloc(x, n); if (new_x) x = new_x; else failure_action();`

Comment: The malloc(1) initialization is needed for _some_ systems, such as SUN OS 4.

Comment: Not sure why I used pastebin if I'm honest...Thanks for the comments and tips, I'll make sure to change my code to check if realloc returns NULL. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The data passed in to `write_data()` isn't necessarily nul-terminated; that's why it tells you the number of bytes.

This means you can't use `strcat()`.  Using it is running off the end of the array and corrupting the data structures used by `malloc` / `realloc`, hence the error.

Your `write_data()` should use `memcpy()` instead, like so:

```
int write_data( char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream )
{
    size_t ThisSize = (size * nmemb); //Stores the size of the data to be stored
    size_t DataLen = RunningSize; //length of the data so far

    RunningSize = (RunningSize + ThisSize ); //update running size (used as new size)

    Data = realloc( Data, RunningSize ); //get new mem location (on the 12th iteration, this fails)
    memcpy((char *)Data + DataLen, ptr, ThisSize); //add data in ptr to Data

    return ThisSize; //the function must return the size of the data it received so cURL knows things went ok.
}
```

You will also need to initialise `RunningSize` to 0, not 1.  You can initialise `Data` to `NULL` - passing `NULL` to `realloc()` is allowed (and makes it behave just like `malloc()`).