# What is the source of this 'realloc(): invalid next size' error

Tags: c, realloc

I've read the other questions of this type, but I still can't figure out why this error is occurring in my code.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {                 
    int len;
    int str[0];
} bit_str;

bit_str * input(void);
void print_bitstr(bit_str * s);

int main(void)
{
    bit_str * s1 = input();
    print_bitstr(s1);

    return 0;
}

bit_str * input(void)
{
    bit_str *s = (bit_str *) malloc(sizeof(bit_str)); 
    int count = 0, bit;

    while ((bit = getchar()) != 'k'){
        s = (bit_str *) realloc(s, sizeof(*s) + sizeof(int));           
        s->str[count++] = bit - 48;
    }

    s->len = count;
    return s;
}

void print_bitstr(bit_str * s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s->len; i++)
        printf("%d ", s->str[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return;
}
```

This code is part of a program I was trying to add two bit strings together (as an exercise from a Data Structures book).

I've created a struct that will store the bits string and it's length. The struct is initialized using a malloc in the input function. It is reallocated every time a new bit is added. The bits are read using a getchar, and the end of a bitstring is demarcated by the letter 'k'.

When I compile the code, it works perfectly for exactly 6 bits. But if I try to input 7 bits, it crashes with following error:

```
> realloc(): invalid next size
```

I've read the other posts with similar error, but I couldn't figure out why this error is occurring in my code here. I've made sure that when I reallocate, I use sizeof operator to get the size, instead of absolute values.

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `int str[0];` is not allowed in Standard C

Comment: I think you should not do this unless you have a lot of experience with C. Use classic allocation method not FMA.

Comment: Indeed, you must use `int str[];`. `int str[0]` is a GCC extension but so would the standard `int str[]` work there - it seems from the error message, that you're using glibc + gcc.

Comment: Also, do not cast the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: The allocation should be`something like `s = (bit_str *) realloc(s, sizeof(*s) + (count + 1) * sizeof(int));`. For the explanation, just read Jonathon'a answer.

Comment: The error message means you've been trampling outside the bounds of the memory that was allocated to you.  There's a bug somewhere in your code; you need to fix it.  The [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) program is excellent for helping with this — use it if possible.  The details of what's wrong with your code are covered in the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [realloc(): invalid next size when reallocating to make space for strcat on char \*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436898/realloc-invalid-next-size-when-reallocating-to-make-space-for-strcat-on-char)

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer,  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  3) when calling `realloc()` assign the returned value to a temporary variable, check that variable, then if the function was successful, then assign to the target variable.  Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails, the original pointer is destroyed, resulting in a memory leak.

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof(*s)` is evaluated at compile-time; it has no knowledge of dynamic allocations such as `malloc` or `realloc`.

So even though you're attempting to dynamically add `sizeof(int)` bytes to the current allocation:

```
s = (bit_str *) realloc(s, sizeof(*s) + sizeof(int));
```

This always causes `s` to point to `sizeof(bit_str) + sizeof(int)` bytes.

Of course, after that no-op `realloc`, you proceed to write more bytes to the buffer, overrunning the buffer and resulting in *undefined behavior*.

Comment: But before I write any bytes to it, I realloc it and increase it's size by one integer. This is done each time I write to it.

Comment: You only ever add one `int` -- you don't keep track of its size. ` sizeof(*s)` doesn't know how big your last allocation was.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: I think you need to explain that `sizeof` works off of static type information, not current dynamic size of the block...

Comment: I think I do, since I use sizeof(*s) + sizeof(int). So reallocate it to be it's own size + the size of one int. Atleast that's what I intend to with my code.

Comment: @Nathu `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time -- it knows nothing about runtime constructs such as `malloc` or `realloc`. Someone owes me a downvote back.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart `sizeof` may be evaluated at runtime, e.g. `int x[rand() % 6 + 1]; printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof x);`.  In this question `s` has type `bit_str *`, so `*s` has type `bit_str` and we are seeing the size of that type

Comment: @M.M I avoided your C99-ism by specifying `sizeof(*s)` :-)